# Calling perl script from perl

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I have a perl script which takes 2 arguments as follows and calls appropriate function depending on the argument. I call this script from bash, but i want to call it from perl, is it possible?

```
/opt/sbin/script.pl --group="value1" --rule="value2";
```

Also the script exits with a return value that I would like to read.

Comment: Why not just call it with require? `require "/path/to/your/script.pl";`

Comment: @konsolebox, Don't `require` files without `package` directive; use `do`.

Comment: Scripts can't return value. Do you mean you want the process's exit code, or do you mean you want to capture its output?

Comment: System worked in my case. I have to do $? >> 8 to get the exit code. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `system` probably returns the same as the `wait(pid, &status)` system call puts into status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl equivalent of `sh` command

```
/opt/sbin/script.pl --group="value1" --rule="value2"
```

is

```
system('/opt/sbin/script.pl', '--group=value1', '--rule=value2');
```

You could also launch the command in a shell by using the following, though I'd avoid doing so:

```
system(q{/opt/sbin/script.pl --group="value1" --rule="value2"});
```

---

Just like you'd have to do in `sh`, you'll have to follow up with some error checking (whichever approach you took). You can do so by using `use autodie qw( system );`. Check the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for how to do it "manually" if you want more flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to capture the output:

```
$foo = `/opt/sbin/script.pl --group="value1" --rule="value2"`;
```

If you want to capture the exit status, but send script.pl's output to stdout:

```
$status = system "/opt/sbin/script.pl --group=value1 --rule=value2";
```

If you want to read its output like from a file:

```
open SCRIPT, "/opt/sbin/script.pl --group=value1 --rule=value2 |" or die $!;
while (<SCRIPT>) ...
```

Comment: System worked in my case. I have to do $? >> 8 to get the exit code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), or [`<backticks>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

The main difference between `system` and `exec` is that `exec` "executes a command and never returns.

Example of system:

```
system("perl", "foo.pl", "arg");
```